# Cannot install openssl 1.1.0 using "nmake install"

Tags: openssl

- OS: Windows 10
- Perl: ActivePerl 5.12.2 build 1202
- Development environment: MS Visual Studio 2010 SP1
- OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0

I tried to compile and install OpenSSL 1.1.0 according to the following steps:

1. decompressed OpenSSL 1.1.0 software package to directory "D:\openssl-1.1.0";
2. opened the "Visual Studio 2010 command prompt" window using an Administrator identity;
3. switched to the directory "D:\openssl-1.1.0";
4. D:\openssl-1.1.0> perl Configure VC-WIN32;
5. D:\openssl-1.1.0> nmake;
6. D:\openssl-1.1.0> nmake test;

> So far, all steps went smoothly, but ...

7. D:\openssl-1.1.0> nmake install;

Here, I got the following error and there was no file being copied to the destination directories even though those directories were successfully created.

```
Microsoft (R) program maintenance utility 10.00.30319.01 copy right (C) Microsoft Corporation.All rights reserved.
```

*** Installing development files
created directory 'C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSL'
created directory 'C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSL/include'
created directory 'C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSL/include/openssl'
Can't Open "./ms/applink.c" at .\util\copy.pl line 61.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: “C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe”: return code “0x16”
Stop.

> The file "applink.c" does exist under directory "./ms".

Comment: Use Strawberry Perl, not Active Perl. I thought there was a similar question recently, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: My problem is solved. I uninstalled ActivePerl 5.12.2 and instead installed the current version - ActivePerl 5.24.0.2400 (64bit). Now, I compiled and installed OpenSSL 1.1.0 successfully.  
Cheers,
Jing

Answer (score -2):

Or, run the Visual Studio compiler as Administrator, not just on an Admin account...

Comment: You should elaborate on your question instead of writing a one sentence long text.